# how to get client list from a router in java

Tags: java

Which is the best way to get the entire connected clients list from a router in java?

I think it should work so:
Configure a Properties object with root/password specified, then pass it through a login-request and at last get the client list.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Little more info will be helpful, what for a router (hw/sw), does it have a webbased management, etc.

Comment: @NwDx
I dont think we need that info especially if we consider the senario of an aplication for the public where you cant predict the router type and capabilities. A LAN scan can do the work but it takes looong... :- (

Comment: Is there a way for any router to do this?

Comment: @user3121190 Which model is your router? Is it a hardware or software router? So, maybe your router already provides an interface.

Comment: it's a hardware router
EDIT: Sitecom 300n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a loop running for every LAN ip for example:
the local machine ip is 192.168.1.2, you are gonna loop from 1 to 255 changing the last number to the loops value and checking if it is reachable. For example:

```
private Collection<InetAddress> findLANMachines() throws IOException {
        String ip = "192.168.1."; //change that to whatever u want :- )
        ArrayList<InetAddress> lanMachines = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 255; i++) {
            InetAddress a = InetAddress.getByName(ip+i);
            if(a.isReachable(2000)) //Change the timeout miliseconds to whatever u want, This may vary depending on the type of network you are on
                                    //and the capabilities of your card.
            lanMachines.add(a);
        }
        return lanMachines;
    }
```

This method will look for every ip and check if it is reachable. I cant say this is efficient by no means but  it is the only way i can think of ATM :- )

**EDIT #1**: In some cases (E.X. public networks or large company buildings) where the devices on the network that claim an ip are more than 255 so the ip's are not enough for all, then other ip's may also be deployed like 192.168.**2**.1 and so on. You can tweak the code above to include those cases as well with a double loop.
I will post a more flexible code for you :- )

**EDIT #2**: Here is a more flexible piece of code to cover the case proposed in EDIT #1, I didnt know how the last two numbers (Seperated by dots) are called in an ip so i called them **depth** and **subDepth**, see the code comments for more:

```
private Collection<InetAddress> findLANMachines() throws IOException {
        int depth = 1; //This number is the range from 1 to X representing * in this ip: 192.168.*.1
        int subDepth = 255; //This is the range from 1 to X representing * in this ip: 192.168.1.*
        int TIMEOUT = 1000;//The ammount to which we need to wait for the other host to reply before we skip to the next one (in ms)
        String ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost().toString().split("/")[1];
        String tmp = ip.substring(0,
                ip.lastIndexOf(".", ip.lastIndexOf(".") - 1))
                + ".";
        ArrayList<InetAddress> lanMachines = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int j = 1; j < depth; j++) {
            for (int i = 1; i < subDepth; i++) {
                InetAddress a = InetAddress.getByName(tmp + j + "." + i);
                if (a.isReachable(TIMEOUT))
                    lanMachines.add(a);
            }
        }
        return lanMachines;
    }
```

This piece of code will take ages to find all hosts but it will work. To decrease this massive ammount of time that it needs to complete, you can consider making this multythreaded. This may NOT be used repetedly because it will cause freezes and consume many resources.
Cheers.

Comment: Hm, a router is a device / software that connects two or more networks, so  with your code you are not able to see the connected devices on that router if they sit in another network segment, like 10.0.0.1. Doing a whole network scan of all private networks might be a fail. If the router have a SNMP / Scripting or anything else Interface, that would be much more a possible solution.

Comment: Glad it helped! But @NwDx is right, i have exploded this possibility  :- (
The code above (Second piece) will run only taking into consideration the network range it belongs to like 192.168.X.X but in case there are other ip's as well it will never contact them :3

Comment: The solution of fillpant will work for you if you only have a little LAN with only one router that only connects to the internet.

Comment: Well, the solution has its limitations networking-wise, as already mentioned. But if the straightforward approach is OK for you, I can only suggest a slight improvement - use http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/util/SubnetUtils.html to loop through IP addresses like this: new SubnetUtils("192.168.1.0/24").getInfo().getAllAddresses(). You can ignore the network and broadcast addresses if needed.